# Is there any way to check the compression ratio of a xz compressed file?

Tags: tar, compression, archive, xz

In windows by default one can see the compression ratio of zip files and after installing WinRAR it also supports this feature but currently I am using a linux and have compressed a file using lzma2 and xz as the container but how can I check the compression ratio without comparing the original file size and the compressed file size? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, just type in a shell terminal

```
xz -l *.xz
```

You can even get more information if you specify option `-v` once or twice.

Comment: Is there a way to also know compression level (`-0`-`-9`) ?

Comment: @sunknudsen  Yes, try option ```-lvv```, then it shows you the used DictSize, e.g. ```--lzma2=dict=16MiB```.  This size can be translated back to the optons ```-0..-9```, according to the table in the man-page: ```man xz```.